# How can I email powershell out in excel format

Tags: powershell

I have a function that queries a database. I want the query results to be send via email in excel format without Human interaction. Is this possible?

```
$Query="SELECT T1.Author,
        T1.Revision,
        T1.Msg AS LogNumber,
        T1.Path as Checkin,
        T2.ThePath as DS_Dependencies
     FROM  Table AS T1
     INNER 
     JOIN Table AS T2
     ON T1.condition = T2.condition"

# redirecting one output stream to the success output stream by using &1
$output = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "sqlInstance" -Database "Database" -Query $Query | Out-String

if ($Output){
    Write-Output "Sending Report"
    $MailUsername = "abc"
    $MailPassword = "xyz"
    $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($MailUsername,(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $MailPassword -AsPlainText -Force))
    Send-MailMessage -To "youremail@tes.net" -From "test@test.net" -SmtpServer mail.test.net -Credential $cred -Subject "Hey testing:" -Body "$Output"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$output | Export-CSV
```

And email the csv to yourself. You can then load it up in excel with the import function :)